# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable when object referenced the second time

Tags: python, oop

I am a total at writing code let alone python. I am facing this error with the following code.
filename is `abcd.py`

```
class device():
    def login(self,ip):
     self.tn= telnetlib.Telnet(ip)

     self.tn.read_until("login: ")
     self.tn.write(login)

    def sendcommand(self,command):
     self.sendcommand= self.tn.write(command)
```

This python code is imported by another file.

```
from abcd import *
def foo():
    ip = 'ip address'


    dev1 = switch()

    dev1.login(ip)

    dev1.sendcommand('cmd1')
    dev1.sendcommand('cmd2')
foo()
```

When I call the foo function everything executes correctly till we reach `dev1.sendcommand('cmd2')`. The error received is

```
dev1.sendcommand('cmd2')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I have simply no clue why its happening. Am I modifying the object in some way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  When you do `self.sendcommand= self.tn.write(command)`, you overwrite the method `sendcommand` with the value of `self.tn.write(command)`.  Use a different name for the variable than for the method.

Comment: perfect!.. noob question!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in the line -

```
def sendcommand(self,command):
    self.sendcommand= self.tn.write(command)
```

You are setting the return value of your writer() to self.sendcommand , which is overwriting the function , you should not do that , just call the function , without setting the return value anywhere . Example -

```
def sendcommand(self,command):
    self.tn.write(command)
```